# Oozie Workflow and Coordinator

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have 2 properties files one for workflow and one for coordinator.
./job.properties and  ./coordinator/job.properties

2 files are identical except in coordinator there are a few additional variables set. below are those variables

```
coordstartTime=2013-04-08T18:40Z
coordendTime=2020-04-08T18:40Z
coordTimeZone=GMT
oozie.coord.application.path=${workflowRoot}/coordinator
wfPath=${workflowRoot}/workflow-master.xml
```

Everything is fine when I run the workflow but I am getting error when I run coordinator
error :
Error: E0301 : E0301: Invalid resource [filename]

that filename exists and when I do hadoop fs -ls [filename] it is listed.

What am I doing wrong here.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was both
    oozie.wf.application.path
and
    oozie.coord.application.path

existed in the coordinator properties file. 
I removed oozie.wf.application.path and the coordinator worked.

thanks